# liferay portal not opening

Tags: apache, tomcat, liferay

I'm new to liferay. I installed the liferay+tomcat bundle and tried to start liferay by running the startup.bat file. The liferay setup wizard should open in the browser by itself but it is not happening. The following is being displayed. How do I open the liferay setup wizard?

Apache - version 2.2.22 
PHP - version 5.4.5 
Server is up and running 
The default Apache context is www in the Apache installation folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems something else is running on port 8080 - e.g. some installation of Apache. You can try this if you just access `http://localhost:8080` without starting tomcat/Liferay first.

Either you need to shut that down, move it to another port or move Tomcat/Liferay to another port. If you want the later, look for a file called conf/server.xml, in there locate the three active `port=...` instructions and change them to unused ports. Then start again.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port number by editing server.xml , you can find it in tomcat>>conf>>server.xml

Change all the ports from 8080 to say 9080 and restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

I mistaken had CATALINA_HOME configured to a different tomcat setup and not the tomcat bundled with Liferay. This made it trigger the port 8080 of the other setup which in return blocked the port before Liferay could listen to it. Make sure CATALINA_HOME is not pointing to some other tomcat installation. Make sure port 8080 , 8005 and 8009 is reserved for tomcat.